# Map values being added to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, syntax, hashmap

I'm having trouble understanding how the last line of code is valid.

```
class Solution {
public List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(String[] strs) {
    if (strs.length == 0) return new ArrayList();
    Map<String, List> ans = new HashMap<String, List>();
    for (String s : strs) {
        char[] ca = s.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(ca);
        String key = String.valueOf(ca);
        if (!ans.containsKey(key)) ans.put(key, new ArrayList());
        ans.get(key).add(s);
    }
    return new ArrayList(ans.values());
}
```

}

The line of code: " return new ArrayList(ans.values());"
**Are the values being inserted one by one- what exactly is happening?**

Comment: can you clarify your question what u want exactly ?

Comment: @Parth Pitroda The answer is returning an arraylist of arraylists. The hashmap has values which are in the form of an arraylist. I was just wondering how "return new ArrayList(ans.values());" is transferring the arraylists into another arraylist.

Comment: ans.values()  bcz your map values in type of list thats why u get arraylist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return new ArrayList(ans.values())`

Break it down and see each instructions

1. `new ArrayList` - new object populated with some values

2 `ans.values()` - values coming from a `collection`: `Map<K,V>` and the method is returning `all V`.

 Note `V` is `List` and `all V` should be a concatenation of all `Lists` (assume references)

Comment: Note also that `ans.put(key, new ArrayList())` , basically it's adding `empty List` at a `key` not sure if this it's useful. So `All Lists` are references to a sum of `empty List`. Fine  as code, but when you add something in most of the cases maybe it's needed with values. (eg: `new ArrayList<String>( Arrays.asList("value1", "value2", "value3")` )

Answer (score 0):

ans.values() returns `Collection<List<String>>` and you need to return `List<List<String>>`. ArrayList class has constructor with Collection as a parameter, see the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-).

Answer (score 0):

According to [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) ArrayList class has the constructor which can construct the list of elements from the specified collection. HasMap is also implementation of interface collection.